# How to compare snapshot with stream using client java API

Tags: java, rtc

What are API to compare snapshot with stream.
I know how to fetch IWorkspaceHandle and IBaselineSetHandle and complete item out of handle, I want to know about method to compare snapshot with stream.  If there is not any direct method then how do we do it.
I used IWorkspaceManager.compareBaselineSets(parameters) method to compare two snapshot. It worked when I passed two IBaselineSetHandle objects.
But I want to compare a snapshot with stream.

Comment: could anyone please tell me?